# Why clang's llvm version is 10.0.0, but the latest llvm version is 7.0.0？

Tags: macos, llvm, llvm-clang

My clang version is `Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)`, but the latest llvm version is 7.0.0, why?

```sh
l:tmp apple$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

[image]

Comment: Apple maintains their own fork of LLVM. It's highly likely that it is versioned differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's forked LLVM version numbers coincide with XCode releases, and so don't directly relate to the upstream versions.

e.g. Apple LLVM 10.0.0 was released with XCode 10.0.