# Which (most recent) llvm version is the correct version for the Android NDK?

Tags: android-ndk

I have 1 or more external dependencies that rely on features that are not available in the prebuilt LLVM-Clang provided with the Android NDK. One such feature is RTTI (Run-Time Type Information). I learned through SO searches that I have to recompile LLVM-Clang to provide features like RTTI. I also saw that the llvm version provided with the NDK was 9.0.8 (this version number might be off).

My question is, what version(s) of LLVM are compatible with the latest NDK, and from what remote repository do I clone from to maintain compatibility with the latest Android NDK?

I have found multiple source URLs for LLVM, but I am not sure which one is correct.

```
https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project/
https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm_android/
https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm/
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project
```

My hope is that as long as I use a version equal to or later than the prebuilt LLVM version from [this repo](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project), I am good to go.

NDK: version r21d, latest as of December 2020

Other links I have looked at:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552782/llvm-version-on-ios-and-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095191/why-clangs-llvm-version-is-10-0-0-but-the-latest-llvm-version-is-7-0-0
```

Comment: "I have to recompile LLVM-Clang to provide features like RTTI" this isn't true.

Comment: Normally, I would agree with you @Dan Albert, but, according to [this document](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support), those that use `ndk-build` don’t have RTTI support by default. I am in the position of still using `ndk-build`, so I need to recompile LLVM. Again, you are not wrong in the general sense; I am dealing with legacy code. My question still stands.

Comment: @robotsfoundme It says, it is "disabled" by default not "unsupported". In the [RTTI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#rt) they have specified the flags needed to enable it.